LSTM dosent learn long term pattern of timeseries
I want to predict a simple time series with a simple lstm model in tensorflow keras. But it seems like the model doesnt learn the long term pattern of the dataset.
The time series data is the airline passengers dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rakannimer/air-passengers/data
The data is normalized to be between 0 and 1. Next for each timestep/targets a timeseries of the previouse 30 elements as input is generated (started by the 30ten element of the dataset)
These inputs and targets then fed into a simple model with 1 lstm layer and 1 dense layer.
From this model, a one-step-ahead prediction is made for 80 steps. Started with the last train timeseries. (every new prediction is used as last element of the timeseries, while the first element is removed)
This leads to a model, which displays the shape of the dataseries but not its slope.
I used following code, validation with the upper part of the airline passengers data is removed to keep the code focused:
def main():
    airline_passengers = AirlinePassengersDataSet()
    train_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_train = train_scaler.fit_transform(airline_passengers.get_train_data().reshape(-1, 1))

    lookback: int = 30
    train_timeseries, train_targets = TimeSeriesGenerator(scaled_train, lookback).create_timeseries()

    model = LSTMModel(lookback)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(train_timeseries, train_targets, epochs=1000, batch_size=1)

    start_index = -1
    start_value = train_timeseries[start_index]
    start_value_reshaped = start_value.reshape(1, start_value.shape[0], start_value.shape[1])
    number_of_predictions = 80
    prediction_results = one_step_ahead_forecast(model, start_value_reshaped, number_of_predictions)

    prediction = pd.DataFrame()
    prediction["one_step_prediction"] = train_scaler.inverse_transform([prediction_results]).flatten()
    prediction.index += airline_passengers.threshold + start_index

    plt.plot(airline_passengers.data["Passengers"], color="red", label="dataset")
    plt.plot(airline_passengers.get_train_data(), color="green", label="training")
    plt.plot(prediction["one_step_prediction"], color="orange", label="one_step_prediction")
    plt.title("airline passengers prediction LSTM")
    plt.xlabel("Time[Month]")
    plt.ylabel("Passengers[x1000]")
    plt.xticks(range(0, 200, 20))
    plt.yticks(range(0, 1000, 100))
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.savefig("./img/airlinePassengers_keras_lstm.png")
    plt.show()

class AirlinePassengersDataSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.read_csv("../../AirlinePassengers.csv", sep=";")
        self.threshold = 107

    def get_train_data(self):
        data = self.data.loc[0:self.threshold, "Passengers"].reset_index(drop=True)
        return data.to_numpy()

    def get_test_data(self):
        data = self.data.loc[self.threshold:142, "Passengers"].reset_index(drop=True)
        return data.to_numpy()


class TimeSeriesGenerator:
    def __init__(self, data, lookback):
        self.data = data
        self.lookback = lookback

    def create_timeseries(self):
        inputs, targets = list(), list()
        for element in range(self.lookback, len(self.data)-1):
            inputs.append(self.__get_timeseries(element))
            targets.append(self.__get_targets(element))
        return np.array(inputs), np.array(targets)

    def __get_targets(self, element):
        return self.data[element]

    def __get_timeseries(self, element):
        return self.data[element-self.lookback: element]


class LSTMModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, lookback):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,
                                   activation="tanh",
                                   recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
                                   input_shape=(lookback, 1),
                                   kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                   recurrent_initializer="orthogonal",
                                   bias_initializer="zeros",
                                   )
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,
                                            activation="relu",
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
                                            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros())

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.lstm(inputs)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        return x


def one_step_ahead_forecast(model, current_value, number_of_predictions):
    one_step_ahead_forecast = list()
    for element in range(0, number_of_predictions):
        prediction = model.predict(current_value)
        one_step_ahead_forecast.append(prediction[0][0])
        current_value = np.delete(current_value, 0)
        current_value = np.append(current_value, prediction)
        current_value = current_value.reshape(1, current_value.shape[0], 1)
    return one_step_ahead_forecast


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The resulting plot looks like this:

Following things I tried, without changes in result:

Increase size of timeseries (up to 50)
Use different model approaches like stacked lstm and bidirectional lstm
variouse changes in epochs, loss function and optimizer

Interestingly with a simple model of dense layers I can achive a much better result. But I wonder why the lstm is not learning the long term pattern of the dataset?

Some ideas for things to try.

The data is normalized to be between 0 and 1.

The LSTM is configured with a tanh activation, whilst the target is scaled to a [0, 1] range. Try aligning them using MinMaxScaler((-1, 1)); this way both the net's output and the target cover the range (-1, 1)`.

a one-step-ahead prediction is made for 80 steps.

This might work for a few steps, but the errors will add up. Rather that feeding the network it's previous prediction in order to make the next one, you could instead shift the window by 1 step, and use that new window to make the next forecast.
The growth trend means that the LSTM will eventually see samples that are outside the range of it's training observations (as the validation data continues to grow larger beyond the training portion). Usually you want to at least de-trend the data. You can add the trend back in later.
De-trending would look something like this: learn the linear/quadratic trend from the training data, and use it to de-trend the training data before training the LSTM. At inference time, de-trend the validation data using the coefficients already learnt in step 1. Then run the de-trended validation set through the model. Finally, add the trend back in (or for simplicity, initially just look at the de-trended results).

self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,

Try a smaller model size, even down to 2 or so units. LSTMs have lots of parameters and easily overfit small datasets.
